# How do this script pause youtube videos?

Tags: javascript, youtube

I noticed [this userscript](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/114002) (which is fairly popular for good reason) pauses the video on another tab whenever I press play on a video in this tab. The source was minified but it appears this is it
https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/blob/master/src/YouTubeCenter.user.js

I had no idea where to start so I search all instance of 'pause'. I thought line 22801 was it but I don't think so anymore. Also I couldn't comprehend what was happening. Typing ytcenter._intercomOnPlayer in the console gave me `undefined`. 8 lines below it (22809) it says "ytcenter._intercomOnPlayer" so I don't think I am reading the right area. I see "@grant           GM_xmlhttpRequest". I looked at the network tab in firebug and saw nothing, at least nothing that appears to be related.

How is it communicating with another tab to pause the video?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is responsible:

```
ytcenter.player.network.pause();
```

[line 22893](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/blob/master/src/YouTubeCenter.user.js#L22893)

I found it via wiki github link https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/wiki/Features#Only_One_Player_Instance_Playing in the code I was looking for "Only_One_Player_Instance_Playing" phrase

Also as I though, tabs can't communicate with each other of course. It has to be done thru youtube api...

**UPDATE**

We have a new question over there. How does that line `ytcenter.player.network.pause()` works?

I werent able to run code on my own. There was some error and I was too lazy to fix it. But I was following `pause` method. First I think that it is native function of youtube api but I was wrong. It is [line 18600](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/blob/master/src/YouTubeCenter.user.js#L18600). Inside is another key

```
intercom.emit("player", {
        action: "pause",
        origin: intercom.origin
      });
```

which leads deeper to `emit` function. As you could guess, `emit` is also not native function of youtube API. It calls `_emit` function and some event. `_emit` is the key one on [line 10754](https://github.com/YePpHa/YouTubeCenter/blob/master/src/YouTubeCenter.user.js#L10754). This is the end, some magic is done inside including `localStorage` and `settimeout`. I belive this is the answer. Local storage is shared and I saw somewhere on my way `setInterval` function. Once video is paused, it emits message into local storage, which is keep just for a short period. Other tabs will notice that via setInterval.

Comment: Interesting. I followed that line to an emitter but I couldnt see what its doing. What is it doing over the network? AFAIK AJAX would only work on google/youtube sites so I don't understand how it would do that over the network. I believe  GM_xmlhttpRequest might do GET and POST request but how is the tab listening for these network events?

Comment: It is interesting question indeed. So I was digging a little bit more and I might have an answer, so I will update current one.